# How to enable/disable Block Completion without using Delphi Options

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm using Delphi 10.3.3. "Block Completion" doesn't work properly for some of my projects, because of an IDE bug fixed in later Delphi versions.

Anyway, I have to use Delphi 10.3.3 and frequently enable/disable Block Completion using Tools -> Options.

[image]

Is there any keyboard shortcut or registry tweak to enable/disable Block Completion?

Comment: See [Key Mappings](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Key_Mappings), which has a link to the built-in key assignments for each of the various supported IDE key mappings. The content is also in the IDE's help files, under "Main Help", if you search for *Key mapings*.

Comment: You could edit the proper registry key for enabling/disabling this setting. But you would always have to close the IDE before the edit and start it again when you're done.

Comment: It's most likely possible to change this setting using the Delphi IDE's Open Tools API, so if there is no existing keyboard shortcut for it, you could create a plugin that adds one. That's not the simple solution you are probably looking for, I know, but I thought I'd mention it anyway.